# Why aren't the fields of the URI class available in PCL?

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library

I noticed recently that the fields on the `System.Uri` class are not available in a PCL.

Specifically, these fields:

```
Uri.SchemeDelimiter
Uri.UriSchemeFile
Uri.UriSchemeFtp
Uri.UriSchemeGopher
Uri.UriSchemeHttp
Uri.UriSchemeHttps
Uri.UriSchemeMailto
Uri.UriSchemeNetPipe
Uri.UriSchemeNetTcp
Uri.UriSchemeNews
Uri.UriSchemeNntp
```

as well as others.

Is there a technical/pragmatic reason why these wouldn't be supported in a PCL? I see in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/URI.cs,25) that these fields (except `Uri.SchemeDelimiter`) come from internal static fields on `System.UriParser`. I then noticed that `UriParser` is not PCL-compatible.

Is that the reason?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason.

Comment: @dotctor, but since eventually these all just come down to string fields, is there a reason that the `Uri` class' PCL version couldn't be adapted to provide these some other way?  This is just curiosity on my part.

Comment: Why should there be a technical reason - why can it not be a pragmatic "if we include everything that's in the .NET Framework, there's no longer a distinction between it and a smaller, more focussed set of APIs that we're happy to commit to supporting across multiple platforms"?

Comment: Good point. It's just curiosity on my part.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If you post that bit about pragmatism and distinction between PCL and the larger .NET framework as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Given how these fields are now in .net core 2.0 it;s unlikely to have anything  to do with "smaller and more focused", and more likely it's the just the case of "we can't port everything overnight" type of things.